# Can the IPv4 CIDRs of the VPC and subnets within be different? (Or they should be within that range)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Say for example I have set 172.31.0.0/16 for the VPC, can I have 172.31.1.0/24 for a subnet within this VPC?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how it works. Did you try it and run into any problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can set block size between a /28 netmask and /netmask, but the CIDR block must not overlap with any existing CIDR block.

It's good practice not use a block that overlap with any CIDR block of other VPC in case you need connect both VPCs.

[Offical Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html)

Answer (score -1):

172.31.0.0/16 means the first 16 bits cannot change which are the right most 16 bits. Rest you can use anyway you want. So 172.31.1.0/24 would be still valid since 172.31.1.0/24 is under the 172.31.0.0/16 range.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote on the answer?